# Android studio3.3.2 error “ADB server didn't ACK, failed to start daemon” on Mac

Tags: android, adb

No target device found.

dev env:

android studio 3.3.2

macOS sierra 10.12.6

> helingyundeMacBook-Pro:platform-tools helingyun$ adb start-server
>
> adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (40); killing...
>
> ADB server didn't ACK
>
> Full server startup log: /var/folders/38/t61kv89122b0vk5ntzhhc_q80000gn/T//adb.501.log
>
> Server had pid: 50120
>
> --- adb starting (pid 50120) ---
>
> adb I 04-08 14:11:37 50120 2064273 main.cpp:56] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
>
> adb I 04-08 14:11:37 50120 2064273 main.cpp:56] Version 28.0.2-5303910
>
> adb I 04-08 14:11:37 50120 2064273 main.cpp:56] Version 28.0.2-5303910
>   adb I 04-08 14:11:37 50120 2064273 main.cpp:56] Installed as /Users/helingyun/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
>
> adb I 04-08 14:11:37 50120 2064273 main.cpp:56]
>
> adb I 04-08 14:11:37 50120 2064276 usb_osx.cpp:308] reported max packet size for HEE6R16128001556 is 512
>
> adb F 04-08 14:11:37 50120 2064273 main.cpp:140] could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
>
> - failed to start daemon
>
> error: cannot connect to daemon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58tp3.png)

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved.  I had Experitest software before installed android studio. the Experitest started a adb process at backend.  the adb process cannot be killed.I unstall Experitest, The problem was solved.